# Using Instances of a Class Within a GUI

Tags: class, user-interface

Using Netbeans 7.4.
I have a GUI with three identical panels and controls in the panels and identical processing for the panels.
I think the right way to do this is define a class and create an instance for each panel.  Then if I have to change the processing I change it in the class and all instances will effect the change.

I created a real simple version that does the "processing" right in line in the ActionPerformed.  I cannot find a way to create the instances so that each one is associated with the proper panel. I assume I should use Netbeans File,New File, Java, Java Class to create a new class file, MyProgram, in the  my.program package.

But where in the UI do I place "MyProgram upper new MyProgram()" the instances of this class and how do I "connect" them to the correct panels.

The simple version is below.  Just three panels. Each has a Left Button and Right Button with a text field that tells you which button was pressed last.  How can I replace the code in the ActionPerformed areas with calls to methods in the appropriate instances.

Thanks In Advance:

****** Code Follows*************

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package my.myprogram;

/**
 *
 * @author Pete
 */
public class MyProgramUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
/**
 * Creates new form MyProgramUI
 */
public MyProgramUI() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */


private void LeftButtonUActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
            jTextFieldU.setText("Left Pushed");
}                                           

private void RightButtonUActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    // TODO add your handling code here:
           jTextFieldU.setText("Right Pushed");
}                                            

private void LeftButtonMActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    jTextFieldM.setText("Left Pushed");
}                                           

private void RightButtonMActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    jTextFieldM.setText("Right Pushed");
}                                            

private void LeftButtonLActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    jTextFieldL.setText("Left Pushed");
}                                           

private void RightButtonLActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    jTextFieldL.setText("Right Pushed");
}                                            



    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MyProgramUI().setVisible(true);


        }
    });
}


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JRadioButton LeftButtonL;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton LeftButtonM;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton LeftButtonU;
private javax.swing.JPanel Lower;
private javax.swing.JPanel Middle;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton RightButtonL;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton RightButtonM;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton RightButtonU;
private javax.swing.JPanel Upper;
private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroupL;
private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroupM;
private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroupU;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextFieldL;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextFieldM;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextFieldU;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your code.  You should post a much smaller, simpler example, without a bunch of autogenerated NetBeans stuff.  However, from your description, it sounds like you should create a custom subclass of JPanel that contains one Left button, one Right button, and one text field.  In the constructor, it would add the two JButtons and the JTextField to itself, and add ActionListeners to the buttons so that the text field was populated appropriately.  Then you would create three of those JPanel subclasses and add them to your main UI.

Comment: I deleted the Netbeans Code. I hope enough remaims.  I wish I could include the GUI image.  When you refer to "the constructor" which constructor?  I just created jPanels, is that different then "a custom subclass of JPanel"?  I get the feeling I am in left field on this.

Comment: Unfortunately now your example has so little code in it that it would not actually do anything if you tried to run it. :)  But I think I do get what you're trying to do.  To summarize: yes, "a custom subclass of JPanel" is different than "a panel".  If you do not know what a subclass is, then you should do some reading on basic object-oriented programming in Java.  For example, try the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html).

Comment: I have been through that a few times.  I could not for the life of me find something in that Tutorial where a GUI uses instances of classes to do somethingI guess I am too far away from understanding java.  All I know about creating panels is to use the netbeans to drag one from the Swing Container.  For someone trying to learn, it seems that everybody has a different way of doing things.  So there is no way to take something from one place and use the concept in another place.  Thanks for your efforts